# Excel file crashes on opening, while opens fine on another computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a `xlsm` file that I saved a couple of hours earlier. I try to open it now, but to no avail. I sent the file to another computer and tried opening it on it and it opens ok. I then tried to send the file back to the current computer and open again, but it still crashes.

I tried deleting `Excel` folder in `AppData` folder, but it didn't seem to work.

What might be causing this issue and what can be done about it?

I have Windows 7 OS and Microsoft Excel 2013.

Comment: Do other files open normally? Have you tried to go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Office -> Repair?